# Magit: Howto create a new commit ignoring white-space differences

Tags: magit, git

I'm using magit 20191128.39 on Emacs 26.3
When changing a python script resulting in a new unstaged change, git/magit should ignore whitespace-differences. A `git diff -w` will do the trick, but I'd like to get the same result inside magit. Any hint here?

Answer (score 3):

In the status buffer, open the diff menu using <kbd>d</kbd>.

From here you can set the `-w` flag by pressing <kbd>w</kbd>.

Many magit commands will pop these menus, when you are changing options you can save the current options as your default settings.

After enabling the `-w` flag, press <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> to save them as your default.

After closing the menu you should see that the status buffer diffs now reflect your preference for `-w`, as well as future diff buffers that you can open via other means.

Comment: You can also change the diff arguments used in the status buffer by beginning the process with `D` instead of `d`.